# Assigning value to variable in data frame based on reference data frame

Tags: r

What's the best way to get a third column in the 'score' data frame that has points assigned based on the 'definepoints' data frame as a reference for assigning scores?

```
players <- data.frame(
  name = c("Bob", "Joe", "Frank"),
  place = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd"))


definepoints <- data.frame(
  place = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd"),
  points = c(10,5,1))

score <- data.frame(
  player = players$name, 
  points = ??)
```

Comment: Just do a merge or join `merge(players, definepoints)`

Comment: well that was simply enough. thanks, didn't know about merge